# What are my options to repair a termite-damaged sill plate?

Tags: repair, termite

I recently discovered a termite damaged sill plate in my basement. Though I don't see any termite activities, I have scheduled a termite extermination service.

I'm preparing to finish the basement, so interior walls will be installed along the foundation perimeter that could provide additional support.

Besides sill plate replacement, are there any other repair options?  Thanks in advance.

[image: sill plate]
[image: corner sill plate]
[image: basement]
[image: exterior sheathing]
[image: door above damaged sill plate]

Answer (score 0):

The main purpose of the sill plate is to anchor down wall bracing, where this bracing provides your house's resistance to horizontal loads like wind or earthquake. That sill looks like it is still capable of serving that purpose. Out of diligence, I would figure out how your walls are braced, where if, for instance, there is a diagonal "let-in-brace" ending immediately above a bad spot, then I might ponder on it harder.

In a typical modern house with OSB sheathing on all of the exterior walls, the bracing provided by the sheathing is pretty well distributed all over the place. In that case, I would probably endorse the exterminator idea and otherwise leave it alone.

The spot at the corner bugs me a little. Typically the first 5 ft at the corners of a house are the spots with undisturbed bracing, where cut in windows, doors, and the like tend to disrupt a lot of the other bracing. For older houses with diagonal "let-in-braces," I anticipate a brace ending right at that spot. For a newer house with sheathing for bracing, I would want to see the exterior wall to verify that there's lots of wall sheathing without openings. Such sheathing implies that there's lots of redundancy even if one bad spot has lost significant strength.

If there's a window or door directly above a damaged spot, then there's absolutely no structural reason to repair that damaged spot. Only very modern patterns of wall bracing use the spaces above and below openings to develop significant strength.

Comment: Thanks @popham.

This is a century house with boards placed diagonally as sheathing.

https://imgur.com/a/i9BEGLc

Yes, there is window and door opening the floor above.  The little nook is an addon outside of foundation and original wall.
https://imgur.com/a/4gzIxlf

Comment: @Jan, unless the sides of the boards are tongue-and-groove with fasteners joining the side-edges, that little patch of diagonal boards to the right of the nook and outside the wall isn't doing a great deal structurally. I expect that the boards are structural when a full length spans from bottom of wall to top of wall (some boards from your image have interruptions, but I see a few with no interruptions--within the frame of the image, anyway). Let-in-braces seem redundant and unnecessary with all of those diagonal boards (assuming that many span from floor to ceiling).

Comment: @Jan, by the modern code, a brace is required within 10 ft of the corner, so something like a let-in-brace would still be required in the corner under today's code, but I have no idea what standards were 100 years ago and in your area. A local remodeler would probably be the best person to ask for insight into whether there's a let-in-brace behind that wall, but I'm betting that there's nothing going on in there.